# Identifying root cause of UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, dll

I am trying to call a function within a dll, but getting an error.
How can I identify the source of it?

```
protected native String parse(String base, String qualifiedType);
    static {

 try {      
        System.load("c:\\lib\\win32\\parser.dll"); //path is correct
   }catch (Exception e){
        e.getStackTrace();
   }    

}

public void parseFoo(){
    String result = parse (name,baseType);
}
```

on calling `parse` I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MyClass.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: Is that method defined correctly in the library? Is it *exported*?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the method signature. The stack trace will show that the exception is being thrown at r native method call, not by `load()`, so it has nothing to do with the DLL path name.

At a guess, you've changed the Java native method signature without adjusting the C code. Regenerate the .h file with `javah` and adjust the C code to agree with it. And make sure you #include the .h file in the .c file.